# SSRS - Merging cells of specific columns

Tags: reporting-services, merge

I am developing a complex report in SSRS which should like below

Screenshot 1
[image: Expected Output Image]

output returned by stored proc have multiple rows of one User ID and based on that columns "Successful Orders -- Online - Total Orders", "Successful Orders -- Online - Total Amount" & likewise Retail - Total, Other - Total columns cells should be merged based on respective User Id.

I have used tablix control and tried adding grouping over columns which needs to be merged but it is not working as expected. in order to group I am setting Sum of returned Value in cell but yet no luck.

Can you please provide me some pointers in order to achieve whats expected. please let me know if you need more information

output after adding nested tablix
ScreenShot 2
[image]

also, distorted output with inner tablix. borders are causing issues
ScreenShot 3
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing a tablix in the cells containing the multiple rows to display them.  Basically, you need to switch your approach from "How do I merge these cells?" to "How do I split these cells."  Set up your grouping at the level you want your totals and then in each of the columns where you want the details displayed, add a tablix to display the details.  You'll need to play with the grouping a bit to get it display correctly.

**More details:**
The sample you provided above should be one group level row, not multiple detail level rows.  Add your group to that Tablix and the summaries you want for your Total columns.  Then Merge each of the "Mode" and "Count" column pairs and insert a Tablix into that merged cell with the same grouping as the row with the Totals, but with only the Details row displayed (don't add group header or footer and delete the blank row and summary column that automatically gets added). Now just set your field values for Mode and Count and adjust your column widths to match the headings.

Here's a REALLY simple report that displays a Plant and the employees associated with that plant.  This is the top level where you Totals group would go.  The next image is the "inner" part, where you would add in another Tablix with the same group(s), but only the details displayed.
[image]
[image]

This is super simple example and you may need to include additional levels of grouping to match your report, but the fundamentals still the same - an "outer" Tablix with an "inner" Tablix with matching group(s).

There's a lot you can do with this approach by manipulating the groups, hiding/displaying different groups or even hiding the details and displaying subtotals.

Comment: Thank you for your response. however I am really finding it difficult to understand since this is something I have never done. will it possible for you to share any example?

Comment: Amazing.... It worked like a charm.. Thank you so much for your help and guidance. I was struggling for lot of time to resolve this and with your help i could do it in few hours. many thanks. I owe you :)

Comment: @user2931668, glad I could help.  This is pretty useful technique.  It's one drawback is that the inner Tablix has to have the same data source as the outer one.  If MS were to change that, it would open up a whole world of flexibility in SSRS reporting.  Sub-reports would be a thing of the past and drill down reports would become super flexible.

Comment: Hello Frank. there is one issue i am facing with it is - in visual studio output looks fine but on IE output is little distorted with inner tablix. it seems they need to adjust dynamically as per their header. also if the user name is lengthy or no multiple rows for mode then also output of inner tablix gets messy. I have attached screenshot in original question above. if you have any tips please suggest

Comment: The way SSRS renders when viewed in a browser can be problematic at times.  We've had slightly better luck using Chrome, but there are still rendering issues when you get into more complex scenarios like this.  The good news is that while the screen rendering may not be correct, the report will still print correctly.  Also, is there a reason why you're using VS studio and not Report Builder?  I've tried both and unless I'm doing something really tricky that demands code, I've found that Report Builder is far easier and faster to author reports.

Comment: I have tried the same report using Report Builder and the output looks fine. but in case of 1st scenario it looks as shown in screenshot 2 above in both(i.e. report builder, VS). in case of export EXcel format is fine but PDF is having issue shown in screenshot 2. this happens when there is no data for particular user and User name is way too lengthy

Comment: any suggestions on these issues?

Comment: Conditionally hide the records with no data.

Comment: cannot hide that row because in last column it does have data. remaining columns which doesnt have data are seen as shown in screenshot2 when exported in PDF. it looks the same even when exported in mhtml document but page source is absolutely ok.